# Two definitions of integral on a sphere: equal? How do I prove that?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

In class, we defined $\int_{S^{N-1}}f\mathrm{d}\sigma$ in the following way. Locally, $S^{N-1}$ is the graph of a map from $\mathbb{R}^{N-1}$, for example the inverse projections, one of which is $\phi(x)=\sqrt{1-|x|^2}$. Locally, we may say:

$$\int_{S^{N-1}}f\mathrm{d}\sigma:=\int_{B_{N-1}(1)}f(x,\phi(x))\sqrt{1+\nabla\phi(x)^2}dx.$$

If $f$ is not supported on one of the sets where the $S^{N-1}$ is a graph, use a partition of unity to reduce the integral to several integrals with integrands supported on such a set, and the use the above expression. Willem's book defines:

$$\int_{S^{N-1}}f\mathrm{d}\sigma:=N\int_{B_N}f\left(\frac{x}{|x|}\right)dx,$$

where $B_N$, I guess, is the $N$-dimensional unit ball. This definition is used to prove polar coordinates integration (cfr. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586874/about-polar-coordinates-in-high-dimensions)), and I would like to add a proof of this fact to my notes, so I would need to show these two are equal and then the proof is from the book. But how are these equal? I was thinking of starting with indicators and then extending to simple functions by linearity, positive functions by monotone convergence, and arbitrary functions again by linearity. But how do I go about the indicator case?

Comment: The reason the second version works is Fubini's Theorem, so the calculation will probably have to make use of this. I think a brute force approach will work fine, along the following lines: write $x\in B_N$ as $x=r(t,\phi(t))$ with $t\in B_{N-1}$ and $0\le r\le 1$, and then run a substitution (from $x$ to $(r,t)$).

Comment: @Christian maybe I'm missing something, but that seems to me more like a suggestion to a possible way of proving the polar coordinates integration formula from the second definition of integral on the sphere, which I have proven in Willem's book. Substituting that, how would I get from second to first? How does that gradient pop up? And did you mean $(r(t),\phi(t))$ rather than $r(t,\phi(t))$?

Comment: It cannot fail to work since you're going to express the second integral as an integral $\int_{B_{N-1}} f(t,\phi(t)) \ldots dt$ and the formula you're trying to prove is correct, so that's what you'll end up with. The substitution formula involves a Jacobian, so you're definitely getting derivatives $\partial \phi/\partial t_k$.

Comment: @Christian The Jacobian is not a square matrix (it has $N-1$ columns and $N$ rows, where the final row.is the gradient of $\phi$ and the rest is the identity), so how do I compute.its determinant?

Comment: I need to add an $r$ coordinate. I.e. to map $(r,t)\mapsto r(t,\phi(t))$. That adds a column which is $(t,\phi(t))$. Now I have a square matrix, and I must have fun with the determinant :).

Comment: I tried writing out the Jacobian in the $N=1$ and $N=2$ cases, and I got $(\begin{smallmatrix} r & t_1 \\ r\phi' & \phi \end{smallmatrix})$ and $(\begin{smallmatrix} r & 0 & t_1 \\ 0 & r & t_2 \\ r\partial_1\phi & r\partial_2\phi & \phi \end{smallmatrix})$, which give me $r(\phi-t_1\phi')$ and $r^2(\phi-t_1\partial_1\phi-t_2\partial_2\phi)$. I guess that will generalize to $r^{N-1}(\phi-\langle t,\nabla\phi\rangle)$. But how does that give me the $\frac{\sqrt{1+|\nabla\phi|^2}}{N}$ I need to get from formula 2 to formula 1? …

Comment: … That $r^{N-1}$ interestingly is what comes up in the polar coordinate integration formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some additional details on the straightforward brute force approach that I suggested in the comments:

Let's run a substitution $x\to (r,t)$, with $0\le r\le 1$ and $t\in B_{N-1}$, and these variables are related by $x=r(t,\phi(t))$. Notice that (except for the origin) this sets up a bijective correspondence between the range indicated and $x\in B_N$. We obtain that
$$
N\int_{B_N} f(x/|x|)\, dx = N \int_0^1 dr\int_{B_{N-1}}dt\, f(t,\phi(t))J(r,t) ,
$$
with
$$
J(r,t) = |\det (\partial x_j/\partial t_k)| = \begin{vmatrix} t_1 & r & 0 && \ldots & 0 \\ t_2 & 0 & r & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ &&&\ldots &&\\ t_{N-1} & 0& 0 &&\ldots & r\\ \phi &r\phi_1 & r\phi_2 && \ldots & r\phi_{N-1}
\end{vmatrix} .
$$
By induction on $N$ (expand along the first row), we find that $J=r^{N-1}|\phi - t\cdot \nabla\phi|$. Since
$$
\nabla\phi(t) = -\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-|t|^2}},
$$
we can rewrite this as
$$
\phi-t\cdot\nabla\phi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-|t|^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{1-|t|^2+|t|^2}{1-|t|^2}} =\sqrt{1+|\nabla\phi|^2} ,
$$
so the first formula is obtained after integration with respect to $r$.

Comment: Where the $N$ cancels out with the $\int_0^1r^{N-1}$ leaving only the integral over $B_{N-1}$, and the $r$ integral only has that since the rest no longer depends on $r$.